# Question about Classification with Least Squares

Tags: classification, least-squares

According to "Statistical Pattern Recognition", from Bishop on page 184, we can solve a Classification problem of classifying $K$-Classes using a Least Squares approach. Now, this certainly is an inferior approach compared to other existing solutions, but I want to understand the intuition behind it.

According to the book, we can

"Consider a general classiﬁcation problem with $K$ classes, with a $1$-of-$K$ binary coding scheme for the target vector $t$. [...]. Each class $C_k$ is described by its own linear model so that

$y_k(x) = w_k^tx + w_{k0}$, where $k = 1, ...., K$.

We can conveniently group these together using vector notation so that

$y(x) = \tilde{W}^T \tilde{x}$, where $\tilde{w_k} = (w_0, w_k^T)^T$ and $ \tilde{x}$ is the augmented input vector$ (1, x^T)^T$.

Now, the problem for me arises with the following statement:

"A new input $x$ is then assigned to the class for which the output $y_k$ is largest."

Intuitively, with this approach I imagine $k$ weight vectors $w_k$, which belongs to one Class, i.e. it it minimizes the Lest Squared Error for that class, similar to Linear Regression. But why can we assign a class in such way, that $y_k$ is largest? I would expect that $y_k$ is closest to the points of class $K$, since $w_k$ does the best job in predicting points for that class (again, similar to Regression). Clearly, I am missing something here.