# What are the implications for performing chi squared tests on ranking data?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, ranking, survey-weights, mnar

I am working with a food preference dataset where individuals rank their food preferences (apple, banana, orange, coconut, pear).  The goal is to determine whether one fruit is ranked as 'favorite' more than another. There are a few interesting aspects to the data:

1. People do not rank fruits they have not tried, so some people may have NA for coconut or pear, for instance.  All people did at least rank 3 fruits.
2. Because it is ranking data, within an individual (row), data are dependent- individuals cannot rank more than 1 fruit first.
3. I'd like to use individual level weights to best represent a larger population.

My thought is to recode all non-first place values to 0, and do the same for NA values since we know why they are NA. However, that leaves the question of how best to build the null discrete probability distribution, since data are missing not at random.

To solve this, I'm generating a respondent level discrete probability distribution and summing them- so if a respondent ranked 3 fruits, the null probability of them selecting any as top is 1/3, with the probability of them selecting those they did not see is 0, etc.  Each cell for that individual would then be multiplied by that individual's weighting variable, so the null discrete probability distribution is representative of the larger population.  Then I would sum these to get an expected frequency table.

Does this approach seem defensible? If not, why not?  If so, does it also hold for the more generalized example of top x ranks (i.e. top 2 fruits, top 3 fruits, etc)? This would essentially double the sum of the null frequency table, but I don't believe that is a problem.

Comment: The following seems relevant to me: Harold Gulliksen, A Least Squares Solution for Paired Comparisons with incomplete data, 1955. 
Online: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/j.2333-8504.1955.tb00052.x

Comment: This question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584519/question-about-classification-with-least-squares may also be relevant. No answer so far.